# MySQL: truncate table - какой документации верить и как лучше очистить таблицу?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Суть такова - периодически необходимо очищать таблицу, в котором накапливается крайне много записей. Можно это было бы делать, просто удаляя их все, но это достаточно долго, да и хочется какого-то более нативного средства. Версия драйверов базы данных: `libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev`, версия БД `innodb_version 5.6.27-75.0`.

Задумался о `TRUNCATE`, но в документации пишут про него по-разному, так, например, [в документации](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/truncate-table.html) на dev.mysql.com (для версии 5.7) пишут вот что:

> Truncation operations cannot be performed if the session holds an
>   active table lock.

И непонятно, как тогда быть, аналога LOW PRIORITY я лично для этой команды не нашел.

А [в документации](http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html) на `nchu.edu.tw` (для версии 5.0) пишут вот что:

> As of MySQL 5.0.8, truncate operations cause an implicit commit.
>   Before 5.0.8, truncate operations are not transaction-safe; an error
>   occurs when attempting one in the course of an active transaction.

Вроде бы, в моей `5.6` уже такой проблемы быть не должно, но точно ли это так? Возможно, есть еще какие-то подводные камни?

Посему, вопрос: как лучше и быстрее очищать таблицу? Я смотрю на такие варианты:

1. Удалять все строки.
2. Использовать `TRUNCATE` и не париться.
3. Использовать транзакцию (не уверен, что это рабочий вариант).
4. Использовать блокировку БД (тоже не уверен, что это рабочий вариант, да и блокировать целиком БД движка - не right way).
5. Использовать блокировку таблицы (тоже не уверен, что это рабочий вариант, но зато не блокируется БД целиком).

*Уточнение: в таблице нет FOREIGN KEY, так что это ограничение для `TRUNCATE` меня не беспокоит.*

**Бонус**: на самом деле это все пишется под `Wordress`, так что, возможно, кто-нибудь знает нативный и безопасный метод от `WP` для сброса таблицы, чтобы не лезть в `MySQL` самостоятельно?

Comment: У вас версия mysql явно не 5.0.11, это версия драйвера/api в php такая ;)

Comment: Я за truncate. И только если пойдут ошибки, искать что-то другое.

Comment: @Visman точно, `innodb_version 5.6.27-75.0` у меня, если верить `SHOW VARIABLES;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, подходящий вариант - номер пять. Цитата [из документации](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables.html) (5.7):

> A table lock protects only against inappropriate reads or writes by
>   other sessions. A session holding a WRITE lock can perform table-level
>   operations such as DROP TABLE or TRUNCATE TABLE. For sessions holding
>   a READ lock, DROP TABLE and TRUNCATE TABLE operations are not
>   permitted.